# How can I get Cimplicity Plant Edition to start up a project faster?

Tags: networking

Using Cimplicity Plant Edition we noticed that some projects seem to take an eternity loading. In particular the process seems to hang during the "ROUTING" phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a setting that really helped speed this up. If you have multiple network interfaces, it appears that Cimplicity takes longer to get through the ROUTING phase. To help it favor the network interface to your devices, go into the Advanced TCP/IP settings for each one and change the "Interface metric" numbers.

This link describes what the Interface Metric settings are for: http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-2000/change-the-interface-metric-on-a-network-adapter/ 
but simply setting these differently on each interface sped things up a lot for us. Hope that helps anyone else out there who is frustrated.